# Iterate through JSON object in Angular Ionic

Tags: angularjs, arrays, json, ionic-framework

I am having difficulty in retrieving blogger.com JSON data using Angular HTTP get method.

If I use `this.posts = data;` I get `Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays.` error and when I use `this.posts = Array.of(data)` the response is inside Array of Array and no output is displayed.

```
jsonApiProvider.myBlogger(1)
    .map(res => res.json().items)
    .subscribe(data => {
        this.posts = Array.of(data);
        console.log(this.posts)
    }, err => console.error(err)
);
```

Here is the screenshot of the final response.
[json response screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uHviF.png)

Response of `this.posts = data; console.log(this.posts)`: [this.posts = data response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4iA5m.png)

**ngFor loop:**

```
<ion-card *ngFor="let post of posts">

    <ion-item *ngFor="let author of post.author">
        <ion-avatar item-left>
            <img src="{{author.image.url}}" />
        </ion-avatar>
        <h2>{{author.displayName}}</h2>
        <p>{{post.published | date:'dd/MM/yyyy'}}</p>
    </ion-item>
    <div *ngFor="let thumbnail of post.images">
        <img src="{{thumbnail.url}}" />
    </div>
    <ion-card-content>
        <ion-card-title>{{post.title}}</ion-card-title>
        <div [innerHTML]="post.content">
            {{post.content}}
        </div>
    </ion-card-content>
</ion-card>
```

How do I iterate through JSON object in Angular (Ionic)? Is my method wrong?

Comment: Can you show output of `console.log(this.posts)` when doing `this.posts = data;`?

Comment: And show your `*ngFor`-code please.

Comment: If that is the output, you shouldnt get that error. Since `this.posts` is an `Array`.

Comment: @robbannn I have included all the details in the main question.

Comment: Awesome! I see you have multiple `*ngFor` directives. Are you sure its the first one including `posts` thats giving you trouble? I cant see all the JSON properties in your screenshots so I cant tell If they are Iterables or not.

Comment: @robbannn you are right. The multiple *ngFor directives were causing the issue. I removed the rest of it and it worked. How do I mark this answer correct?

Comment: I will provide a real answer soon, that you can accept. Great it worked out for you!